# Image displaying in UITableviewCell from url

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

Here is my code to display images in tableview cell from url.

```
 cell1.tag = indexPath.row;

    dispatch_queue_t Queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(Queue, ^(void){

        NSData * imgData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:images[indexPath.row]]];

        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (cell1.tag == indexPath.row) {
                    cell1.img.image = image;
                    [cell1 setNeedsLayout];
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

using this i get images but not in synchronously manner.
how to download images synchronously?

Comment: Paste sample full image url here

Comment: http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music30/v4/9a/40/23/9a402364-cb4e-9922-7125-4d49b24faacb/rm_image.jpg/170x170bb-85.jpg  @kb920

Comment: Loading data *synchronously* from a remote URL with `dataWithContents...` is always a bad idea even in an asynchronous dispatch block.

Comment: ok..then there is any other way to download image from url? @vadian

Comment: @Sweta Vani Check imgData is null or not.

Comment: check the url you are passing as a parameter to `dataWithContentsOfURL:` try to print it and check, is it correct?

Comment: imgData is not null

Comment: yes..with single url it shows image but i want to display multiple so i have images array which contains url. @Sunny

Comment: @SwetaVani You should use Asynchronous image downloader like `SDWebImage`

Comment: okay..thanku for help

Comment: are you using custom Cell? if you are using it so i have a code i will give it to you.

Comment: yes..i'm using custom cell.@Dishant Rajput

Answer (score 0):

two options:

1.) you need to return cell at the end of the method, or

2.) go for Pod named : Kingfisher. you'll find it on github.